# Can you show which items are bound to a PDO statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using PHP, MySQL, PDO

For logging/debug purposes,  I would like to be able to log which sql query ran, is it possible to get this value with all the bound results attached to it?

I saw `PDOStatement->debugDumpParams` but it does not seem to give the values that are bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: the query (unless emulated) *does not exist*. It never got there as a raw query, hence the safety of it all. The best you can hope for is usually [`debugDumpParams`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)

Comment: It's extremely useful for "logging/debug purposes", what did you think you'd get and how did you plan to use it?

Comment: I guess it would be more useful to me if it contained the values of the placeholders instead of just the names and data types

Comment: In that case, you'll want to extend `PDOStatement`, and capture those values in `bindValue`, `bindParam` & `execute`.